# Is it possible for an Object to have a different size in bytes after re-serialization?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, stream

In Java, I created an object, serialized it into an array of length 642 bytes, made it back into an object, serialized that object, and got an array of length 651 bytes. How and why did this happen? I thought the length of the object should be consistent with repeated serialization, because the length has been the same in other objects that I have serialized and deserialized. Note that after subsequent de-serializations and re-serializations, the length remains at 651 bytes.

Here is my code:

```
PrivateIPV4_Reliable object = new PrivateIPV4_Reliable();
final byte[] data = ByteArrays.ObjectToByteArray(object);
AppTester.print("Serialized an PrivateIPV4_Reliable of size: " + data.length); 
// 642 bytes

PrivateIPV4_Reliable deSerialzed = (PrivateIPV4_Reliable) ByteArrays.MakeByteArrayIntoObject(data);
byte[] deserializedBytes = ByteArrays.ObjectToByteArray(deSerialzed);
AppTester.print("Reserialized it into object of length: " + deserializedBytes.length + "\n"); 
// 651 bytes

// Why does the object get bigger after re-serialization?
// This size increase did not happen with another object that I serialized and de-serialized.
```

*** Update 1 ***

Here is the byte arrays in hexadecimal format:

Byte array after first serialization: (length: 642)

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

Byte array after second serialization:(length: 651)

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

Byte array after third serialization (length: 651, identical to second serialization)

*** Update 2 ***

Here is the object being serialized/de-serialized:

```
package Core_Reliable;

import Utilities.AppTester;
import Utilities.ByteArrays;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.InetAddress;

/**
 * @author johnmichaelreed2
 */
public final class PrivateIPV4_Reliable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6352314532134833L;

    private final InetAddress[] myPrivateAddresses_;
    private final int myPrivatePort;
    private final long myTimeOfInstantiation_;

    public PrivateIPV4_Reliable(InetAddress privateIPs[], int privatePort) {
        AppTester.check(privateIPs != null, "No null values in initializer.");
        this.myPrivateAddresses_ = privateIPs;
        this.myPrivatePort = privatePort;
        this.myTimeOfInstantiation_ = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public boolean deepEquals(PrivateIPV4_Reliable other) {
        return ByteArrays.deepEquals(this, other);
    }

    public InetAddress getCopyOfInetAddressNumber(int index) {
        InetAddress copy = ByteArrays.tryDeepCopy(this.myPrivateAddresses_[index]);
        AppTester.check(copy != null, "Failed to deep copy my InetAddress");
        AppTester.check(copy instanceof InetAddress, "The copy isn't an InetAddress");
        return copy;
    }

    public InetAddress[] getInetAddressesCopy() {
        AppTester.check(myPrivateAddresses_ != null, "No null private address lists.");
        return ByteArrays.tryDeepCopy(myPrivateAddresses_);
    }

    public int getPrivatePort() {
        return myPrivatePort;
    }

    public long getTimeAtInstantiation() {
        return myTimeOfInstantiation_;
    }
}
```

Here is the method I used for serialization:

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(final Object object) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.flush();
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        // get the byte array of the object
        byte[] obj = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.flush();
        baos.close();
        return obj;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppTester.printEx(e);
        System.exit(-78);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the method I used for de-serialization:

```
public static Object makeByteArrayIntoObject(byte[] data) {
    AppTester.check(data != null, "Null data");
    Object to_return = null;
    try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))) {
        try {
            to_return = ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            AppTester.printEx(cnfe);
        } catch(StreamCorruptedException sce) {
            AppTester.printEx(sce);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        AppTester.printEx(ioe);
    } finally {
        return to_return;
    }
}
```

Where "AppTester" is my custom logging/debugging/assertion class. (see [JohnsAppTester](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/LogAppTester))

Comment: There are lots of possible explanations for this.  Show us the class that is being serialized / deserialized.

Comment: The class that is being serialized/deserialized is pretty unremarkable, it doesn't even have any transient variables or any special serialization methods in it. It just contains an ArrayList of java.net.InetAddress, a byte array, and an int. I'll show it to you.

Comment: I added the code... do you think that maybe Netbeans is using the wrong version of the class - I've been having a bug where class not found exceptions occur because something was wrong with the IDE storing or using old/wrong version of my classes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure what is causing the problem is to use some tool to compare the two versions of the serialization as a stream of bytes, and then reverse the serialization by hand based on what the spec says.

However, one possibility is that there have been "binary compatible" changes made to the class `PrivateIPV4_Reliable` between the original serialization and the re-serialization.  If you suspect that you have multiple versions of the class, then that *could* explain it.

Note that the Java Object Serialization protocol / format does not guarantee that serializations will be identical.

Comment: Note that after subsequent de-serializations and re-serializations, the length remains at 651 bytes. It's strange - this didn't happen for my other classes.

Comment: Would you like me to print out the object byte arrays in hexadecimal format?

Comment: It starts to change after "45787371007E0005000000000000000270780000000301017" in the hex.

Comment: (Part of my reluctance in helping is that I actually don't understand what the point of this is.  What difference does it make if the serialized object's size changes? What problem are you >>really<< trying to solve here?)

Comment: Well, I am serializing my private ip addresses, sending them to a server, and having the server send them back to me along with some other stuff. The class that holds my ip addresses and port (Private_IPV4_Reliable), it has a deep equals method that allows it to compare the version of itself in the client to the version of itself that the server sends back. The client sends the object, the server sends it back, or it might send back a modified object. In my code, the client then checks if the received version is DEEP equals to (binary equals to) the original which it sent out.

Comment: For other classes, this method worked fine. In fact, up until now, it worked fine FOR THIS EXACT CLASS. The only thing I did was increase the number of ineraddresses in the array and maybe change the serialVersionUID at one point, but besides that, I see no reason for my deep equals method to become invalid all of a sudden.

Comment: I mean, I'm sure I could just compare all the fields inside this object instead of serializing the entire thing, but doing it this was has worked in other cases and I don't see why it stopped working all of a sudden.

Comment: Yes.  That is what you should do.  Comparing serialized objects is inherently fragile.